# Three part names to compare objects between DB2 Subsystems

Tags: sql, db2, cobol

When I tried to use three part names to compare objects between subsystems, using the following query:

```
SELECT A.NAME, A.DBNAME 

FROM SYSIBM.SYSTABLES A

WHERE NOT exists (SELECT * FROM rem1.SYSIBM.SYSTABLES B
                  where B.NAME = A.NAME )
WITH UR;
```

I get the following error:-

> SQLCODE = -512, ERROR: STATEMENT REFERENCE TO REMOTE OBJECT IS
>       INVALID

Is there any workaround available?

Answer (score 0):

(Perhaps not the solution, but at least a correction.)

You need a *correlated sub-query* for the `NOT EXISTS`:

```
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM rem1.SYSIBM.SYSTABLES B WHERE B.NAME = A.NAME)
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response  but i have tried this one too it didnot work.

Comment: Can you do `SELECT * FROM rem1.SYSIBM.SYSTABLES` stand-alone?

Comment: I see. Well, you need dynamic SQL here, or a stored procedure, where you for put the actual rem1 _value_ in the query before executing it.

Comment: Could you please explain in Detail? Any example would be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:
If You want to join tables from another instance/server using its alias You need to create wrapper, server and nickname. If all goes OK query from your post should work.

[CREATE WRAPPER](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0002173.html)

[CREATE SERVER](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0002170.html)

[CREATE NICKNAME](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0002169.html)

Comment: Thanks for your solution. Is it compatible with DB2 Z/OS?

Comment: The previous solution was for MS SQL. I edited my post.

Comment: Thanks. But I am not authorized to create any of these. Have you tried it before, because i donot even know if these Kind of Queries can be written?

Comment: If You don't have sufficient permision Your query won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Db2 LUW supports Federation concept. You may follow this document: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/db2luwtechsupport/entry/how_to_setup_federation_between_two_db2_luw_databases2?lang=en

I am not sure if this applicable to Db2 zOS though.